# Facebook webhook for Ads (Marketing API)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks, facebook-marketing-api

Is it possible to make a facebook webhook for event of approving the ad.
When you create an ad, it's in `pending review` status that can take some undefined time. I need to call some actions right after the ad is approved.

There are facebook webhooks for apps/pages/users. But what about Ads?

Comment: Have a look at [**ricks**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52938866/3679900) which points to [Ad Rules Engine](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/ad-rules)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no webhooks for Ads, webhooks only exist for Pages and Users. Here are all the possibilities: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks

Edit:

My bad, there ARE webhooks for Ads: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving#webhooks

Answer (score 7):

Actually @luschn, there are webhooks for certain Marketing API features.

Such as:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/webhooks/v2.5