# Are there any marketing API webhooks for modifying campaigns/adsets/ads

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

In the program i am writing users can pause/unpause a campaign.

I want to know if theres a way i can update the status of the campaign on my end if the user modify the campaign through the Facebook Ads manager.

The only webhooks i could find are for [lead generation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like i found the documentation hidden [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/ad-rules-getting-started/)

You have to *add ads_rules_engine Webhook to your app* in order to recieve webhooks for